# Find the count of all the matching elements in an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to find the count of all the matching array elements and count = 0 if the nested array do not contain values.
    Here is my data entity structure.

```
{
  name:A,
  issues:[1,2,3,4]
}
{
  name:B,
  issues:[1,2]
}
{
  name:C,
  issues:[3,4]
}
```

If user search for `issues:[1,2]`, I want my result set to look like

```
[{
  name:A,
  count:2
}
{
  name:B,
  count:2
}
{
  name:C,
  count:0
}]
```

I am  using below query to achieve this but it only returns me result

```
[{
  name:A,
  count:2
}
{
  name:B,
  count:2
}]
```

which definitely  I know because of the $match I am doing

```
 {'$unwind':'$issues'} 
 ,{'$match':{'allissues': {$in: p.issues? p.issues.map(Number):[]}}}
 ,{ '$group' :{_id:'$_id', name :{ $first: '$name' },count: { $sum: 1 }} }'
```

Comment: you can try something like this. `db.collection.aggregate([        {          $project: {            count: {$size: {        $setIntersection: [p.issues, "$issues"]                  }                }            }        }      ])`

Answer (score 2):

Given that `issues` variable is the array input by users, you do not need to use a three-stages aggregation like above to get the result. You just need to find the intersection of users input and `issues` field of each document, then get length of the result arrays. This code will do the job:

```
db.col.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    count: {
      $size: {
        $setIntersection: [issues, "$issues"]
      }
    }
  }
}])
```